# Add Value in table From the database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is the simplest way to insert values in a table. I want to insert values from the database table into my JTable. Can someone provide me an input?

```
String columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

// Create some data
String dataValues[][] =
{
    { "12", "234", "67" },
    { "-123", "43", "853" },
    { "93", "89.2", "109" },
    { "279", "9033", "3092" }
};

// Create a new table instance
table = new JTable( dataValues, columnNames );

// Add the table to a scrolling pane
scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
topPanel.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
```

Answer (score 2):

Create and View the Database Table in Java Swing

```
DefaultTableModel dm=new DefaultTableModel();
```

[REFER THIS](http://java4practices.blogspot.in/2012/12/create-and-view-database-table-in-java.html#more)

Comment: bro u first try separately steps mentioned in the post it will definitely work because i used in my project.

Comment: bro r u include database jar file properly

Comment: r u followed the steps properly in the post

Comment: yeah i followed the step.. but actually i am using eclipse not netbeans but i start following from the 6th step in which the method is present

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33117/discussion-between-ganesh-rengarajan-and-mind-blowing)